# rails nested form error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I have a nested form that when the form isn't successfully submitted (the user forgot a required field), on reload, the nested form portion isn't fully displaying again...

what doesn't display are the constraints on the nested part that weren't met...

So there's two fields for the nested form first day and last day, that can't be blank to be saved.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :onespecials, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:first_day].blank? || a[:last_day].blank? }
```

However, if a user doesn't fill these out, clicks submit, and messes up one of the fields above on the main form, the nested part doesn't display again... Any help on how to get all the nested pieces to show up when it has to reload because of an error on the form?

Comment: This probably has to do with how you're A) building the nested attribute and/or B) how you're rendering existing nested objects on your form. You didn't show either of those as code snippets, so this is rather hard to diagnose.

Comment: updated with code... does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Of corse nested form will be blank - you rejected arguments for it: `:reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:first_day].blank? || a[:last_day].blank? }`. That's why you just doesn't have `f.object. onespecials`. If you would like to validate `one specials` use validate method or standard methods for validation. Another words just remove `:reject_if` and you will have rendered form with filled out fields.

Comment: but I don't want the blank fields to be saved in the database if they don't type anything in, for the nested part.

Comment: use `validates_presence_of` for fields in `Onespecial` model